# Creating a range of solutions using NSolve

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I am using `NSolve` to find roots of complex equation. Typical code  is in the form of

```
f[a_, b_] := x^a + x^2 - b ;
NSolve[f[4, 3] == 0 && Abs[x] < 10, x]
```

The above code finds say four roots of the equation. How do I create set of roots for range of  `b` = 1 to 4 and plot line x1 vs i, x2 vs i, x3 vs i etc.

I used

```
f[a_, b_] := x^a + x^2 - b;
DiscretePlot[x/.NSolve[f[4, i] == 0 && Abs[x] < 10, x], {i, 0, 4, 1}]
```

It does the plot I want to see, but I have a problem assigning colour for each `x` root or `(x1, x2, x3, x4)`. Note that I am assuming my complex function always gives four roots.

Comment: The roots are `(x /. NSolve[f[#, 3, 2, 2] == 0 && Abs[x] < 3, x]) & /@ Range[4]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the "typical" `f` is a polynomial, then you can use [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) instead of `NSolve`.

```
ClearAll[f, roots, a, b, x];
f[x_, a_, b_] := x^a + x^2 - b;   (* need the polynomial to be a _function_ of x *)
roots[a_Integer?Positive] := Table[Root[f[#, a, b] &, k], {k, a}];
```

I'll plot the imaginary parts in a `Dashed` style.

```
(* SetAttributes[ReIm, Listable];   (* uncomment for V9 & earlier *)
   ReIm[z_] := {Re[z], Im[z]};  *)
plots = Table[
   Plot[ReIm@roots[4][[k]] // Evaluate,
    {b, -1, 1},      (* increase range to ±10 if desired *)
    PlotStyle -> {ColorData[97][k], Directive[ColorData[97][k], Dashed]}],
   {k, 4}];
GraphicsGrid@Partition[plots, 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Show[plots, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I am getting 2 error messages in Mathematica v9. 1) ColorData::notent: 97 is no known entity, class or tag for ColorData. User ColorData[] for a list of entities.     2) 
Part::partw Part 2 of {-1,0,0,1}[4] does not exist

Comment: @Aschoolar Try `ColorData[1]` instead of `ColorData[97]`.  With V10, WRI changed the color scheme for plots. (There were many changes with V10. You might want to mention you're using V9 in your questions, and folks will probably try to keep to V9-compatible solutions, as best as they can remember.)

Comment: If that doesn't fix point 2), perhaps you redefined `roots`.

Comment: (I just noticed I remembered `ReIm` was new, but for about `ColorData[97]`. )

Comment: ColorData[1]  solved the problem and I will keep in mind about version used every time I post a question.

Comment: it works nice.  But my equation has funny behaviour.  It has coefficients such that for some input parameters  the coefficient vanish.  Please see my post for toy example...." Is it possible to align roots to plot consistently?" You can see the reason why we don't want to pad breaks with zeros..Is it possible with your plot routine? My equation is a 32 degree polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
f[a_, b_] := x^a + x^2 - b;
xx=Range[0,4,1];
yy=Re[Table[x/.NSolve[f[4,i]==0 && Abs[x]<10,x],{i,0,4,1}]]
data=TemporalData[yy,{xx}];
ListLinePlot[data,BaseStyle->PointSize[0.02],PlotRange->{-2,2}]
```

It plots only real part.  For imaginary switch from Re to Im.